# sum for trailing 365 days from a purchase date for users

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions

I'm trying to find the sum of amount for an 'ID' trailing 365 days from the 'DT'. Below is a sample from the data I'm working on. The below table consists of dates when purchase was made , id and the amount. I wanted to calculate amount spent by an id trailing 365 days from the 'DT'. Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
DT      ID  AMT
1/17/15 1   31.74
1/23/15 1   14.33
1/25/15 1   21.76
3/5/15  1   150
6/12/15 1   60
4/23/16 1   16.86
4/25/16 1   60
7/1/16  1   15.57
2/26/15 2   61.9
3/1/15  2   15
2/28/16 2   25
```

I want my output to be

```
DT      ID  AMT     outstanding_amt
1/17/15 1   31.74   31.74
1/23/15 1   14.33   46.07
1/25/15 1   21.76   67.83
3/5/15  1   150     217.83
6/12/15 1   60      277.83
4/23/16 1   16.86   76.86
4/25/16 1   60      136.86
7/1/16  1   15.57   92.43
2/26/15 2   61.9    61.9
3/1/15  2   15      76.9
2/28/16 2   25      40
```

I have tried `sum(amt) over(partition by user_id)` but this gives me cumulative sum for all the dates. I do not know how to condition it with the date condition

Answer (score 2):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.amt)
        from t t2
        where t2.id = t.id and
              t2.dt <= t.dt and
              t2.dt > t.dt - interval '365' day
       ) as outstanding_amt
from t;
```

This might have reasonable performance with an index on `(id, dt, amt)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would just change the order by clause like the example below.

```
select dt
, id
, amt
, sum(amt) over(order by dt rows unbounded preceding) as rollingsum
from table
where 1=1
and dt between current_date - 365  and current_date
```